# Android - How can an app with only debug & release buildTypes use a multi flavor library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

## Question

How can an app with only debug & release buildTypes use a multi flavor library?

### Details

I have a project containing two modules: `app` and `mymodule`.

The `app` module has no flavor with only debug and release buildTypes. This is the app `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    default {
    ....
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

The `mymodule` has two flavors: login and registration which share the same base codes. This is mymodule `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    default {
    ....
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'version'
    productFlavors {
        login {
        }
        registration {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

In `mymodule`, the codes are separated into source set like this so that I can build *login.aar* or *registration.aar*, but also let them share the base code from `src/main/java`. I also would like to use `mymodule` in `app` module.

```
|-src/main/java/
|-src/login/java
|-src/registration/java
```

This is `settings.gradle`.

```
include ':app', ':mymodule'
```

### What I've tried

I've added the dependency `implementation project(':mymodule')` into app `build.gradle`, but I received the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: have you added the modules in settings.gradle?

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns, yes I have. I've edited my post to include the content of `settings.gradle`.